# To find the 9th Fibonacci Prime number

Tags: python, python-3.x, fibonacci

I'm not sure if this is the right place to ask but  I have run into a wall, code-wise. I am trying to find the 9th Fibonacci number which is a Prime number but am having problems. First, my function to check if the number is Prime returns None for single digit prime numbers (2,3,5,7). Next, I think the value I'm looking for is 514229 as shown [here](http://www.maths.surrey.ac.uk/hosted-sites/R.Knott/Fibonacci/fibtable.html) but my program shows gives me the value 17711 as the 9th Fibonacci prime which is incorrect. My code is posted below:

```
def isPrime(n):


    n = abs(int(n))

   if n < 2:
        return False


    elif n == 2:
        return True


    elif not n & 1:
        return False

    else:
        for x in range(3, n/2):
            if n % x == 0:
                return False
            return True


def chkFibonacci():

    num1 = 1
    num2 = 1
    mySum = 0
    ctr = 0
    choice = 'n'

    while (choice != 'y'):
        mySum = num1+num2
        #print mySum
        if (isPrime(mySum)== True):
            ctr = ctr + 1
            print mySum
            if (ctr == 9):
                print mySum
                break
        num1 = num2
        num2 = mySum    

chkFibonacci()
print isPrime(3)
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`return True` in the `else` branch of `isPrime` seems to be indented too much.